# Comparing 2D np arrays with ssim: ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent. If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ssim

*I am trying to calculate SSIM for 2 numpy arrays using structural_similarity from skimage.metrics:*

```py
ydata.shape = (3, 230)
ydata3.shape = (3, 230)
```

*When I try to calculate SSIM:*

```py
mse_value = mean_squared_error(ydata, ydata3)
ssim_value = ssim(ydata, ydata3, data_range=ydata3.max() - ydata.min())**
```

*I have the error:*

```py
"win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel "
ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True.**
```

*I tried to set `multichannel = True` but it does not work.*

```py
ssm: ssim_value = ssim(ydata, ydata3, multichannel= True, data_range=ydata3.max() - ydata.min())
```

*I also tried to increase the dimension of the array with:*

```py
ydata = ydata.reshape(ydata.shape[0], ydata.shape[1], 1)
```

The new shape of the arrays is ((3, 230, 1), (3, 230, 1)).
*However it keeps showing the same error*

I tried also flatten but it changes a lot my results.

Any suggestions or help?

Comment: By _"I tried `multichannel = True`"_, do you mean you set a variable `multichannel` in your global scope to `True`? It very likely means you need to set `ssim.multichannel = True` or some attribute of the _module you're using_. (IDK what that is)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to get the SSIM when comparing two images in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585571/i-want-to-get-the-ssim-when-comparing-two-images-in-python)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, I set multichannel=True when calculating ssm:  ```ssim_value = ssim(ydata, ydata3, multichannel= True, data_range=ydata3.max() - ydata.min())```.    I am using  structural_similarity from skimage.metrics.   Thank you for the answer suggestion, but I tried already to increase the dimension of the array with ```ydata = ydata.reshape(ydata.shape[0], ydata.shape[1], 1)```  . The new shape of the arrays is ```((3, 230, 1), (3, 230, 1))``` . However it keeps showing the same error. And they are float datatype.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the skimage library, so I wouldn't be able to answer your question. Just want to reconfirm that you passed the `multichannel=True` argument _to your `ssim` function call_, and still got the same error? Because in the code you show in your question, you don't pass that argument.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you . I passed ```multichannel= True```, however it seems that it is only accepted when the shape is > 7 and it is 3 in one dimension, for example, if the shape is (9,230, 1), ```multichannel= True``` is passed and I do not have errors, however, when I increase the value of the dimension the results are so incongruous for what I am trying to compare.